# Secure file download phonegap (hide params)

Tags: file, post, cordova, download

I am downloading a file from a server and saving it in my device. All is working properly but the problem is that the url contains explicitly the user and password. For example:

```
fileTransfer.download(
URL+"?strUser="+user+"&strPassword="+pw+"&id="+id+"&type=file",
"path"+fileName,
```

Can you help me to find a secure way to download files from server?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things come to mind - one - ensure you are at least using https. Second - only send the u/p one time to the remote server and ask for a unique token. Use that token for further network calls and ensure the token has a timeout. That way if someone *does* get the token they can't use it (at least not for long).